# How can I view samples of my Open Graph stories on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Back in December I created Open Graph stories on Facebook. And I could view samples of them immediately after creation. I'm talking about these ones:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RX76.png

Today I've created a couple of new stories. But for some reason I can't view their samples. I get the message "Unable to Generate Story".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqlzl.png

Seems like the UI has been changed since then. So guys... how do I view Open Graph stories samples?

Thanks in advance!

Ilya

P.S. The "10 reputation points to post any pictures" rule is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish these stories first then you will be able to view the preview/sample inside your app.

You can use the OpenGraph Explorer to do this.